# Is it normal Aurora serverless v2 mysql instances always using over 90% of cpu capacity?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-aurora-serverless

Even without connections and with no data stored on it, my aurora serverless v2 mysql instances are hitting 90%, sometimes 98% of cpu usage. This is something that doesn't sounds good to me. Is this okay?

[image]

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-aurora-postgresql-high-cpu/

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary it doesn't applies to this case. I have no tables, no connections, nothing! And also I'm using MySQL

Comment: Did you check any other metrics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0.5 ACU translates to 1GB of RAM and 1 vCPU. That's very limited resources, inside of an RDS box you have other processes running beyond the engine, that's why you are seeing almost all resources being consumed. AWS doesn't recommend a configuration of min and max ACU = 0.5.

"The maximum capacity must be higher than 0.5 ACUs. You can set the minimum and maximum capacity to be the same in most cases. However, you can't specify 0.5 for both the minimum and maximum. Use a value of 1 or higher for the maximum capacity."

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless-v2.requirements.html#aurora-serverless-v2.max_capacity_considerations

Comment: Adding some information for future accesses: Now AWS doesn't allow set 0.5 as max ACU anymore.

Comment: Is there a source for "0.5 ACU translates to 1GB of RAM and 1 vCPU" specifically? I haven't seen the the .5 ACU = 1vCPU specified anywhere in the documentation. They just say "corresponding CPU" which leaves one wondering...

Comment: Here is a [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless-v2.requirements.html#aurora-serverless-v2.requirements.capacity-range) to the documentation. "Aurora Serverless v2 capacity ranges from a minimum of 0.5 Aurora capacity units (ACU) through 128 ACUs, in increments of 0.5 ACU. Each ACU provides the equivalent of approximately 2 gibibytes (GiB) of RAM and associated CPU and networking"

Comment: Pricing wise this is quite annoying. 0.5v CPU can't run any useful workloads and that's roughly US$70/mth. Effectively 1 ACU is required to do minimal workloads? ~140/mth? That's roughly 50%+ a single AZ medium which is already 2 vCPU/4GB. Scalability is very expensive.